# the strange java code when using Summarize

Tags: java, generics

I have a code block listed below:

```
public class {
    private static Boolean b (String a){
            return false;
    }
    public static void testFunction(Function<?,Boolean> whatever){

    }
    public void test() {
        Function<String, Boolean> noUse = Demo::b;
        testFunction(noUse);


        testFunction((Function<String,Boolean>)Demo::b);
        //why it's wrong
        testFunction(Demo::b);
    }
}
```

I'm confused by `testFunction(Demo::b)`.
It's obvious that function b has signature `Boolean(String)` which exactly matches `Function<?, Boolean>` due to convarint. And `Function<String, Boolean> noUse = Demo::b` proves this.
But why the statement is wrong `testFunction(Demo::b)` ?

I have searched it in google and chatgpt. But I can't summarize it quite well.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `?` is any type. That means, it can be a `Object`, a `String`, a `Boolean`, etc.

If you change your test function to the following, it will take your second call.

```
public static void testFunction(Function<? extends String, Boolean> whatever)
```

With `? extends String` you limit the range of the type to `String` and all subclasses, whereas before it was `Object` and every other type.

Also you can notice that if you change the method to `private static Boolean b (Object a)`, you can pass it to the method `testFunction` without any changes.

If you call your function with explictly stating the function, you see that it expects an `Object`.

```
testFunction(new Function<Object, Boolean>() {

    @Override
    public Boolean apply(Object o) {
        return null;
    }
});
```

Since your method `b` is explictly taking a `String`, you need to make sure that a `String` is passed to the method.

This can be done by explictly stating your function (1. call), or casting your function. Another way can be by casting your parameter to `String`, which is passed to the function.

```
testFunction(parameter -> b((String) parameter));
```

Comment: So basiclly `Function<?,Boolean>` type is equals to `Function<? extend Object,Boolean>`.And when calling the testFunction directly with `demo::b`,the compiler treats it's type as the `Function<Object,Boolean>`, which is wrong.But the type or signature of `Demo::b` itself is determined, why the compiler can't cast it automatically.

Comment: By automation I mean the compiler found out the `testFunction` takes `Function<? extend Object,Boolean>`   as parameter, and now the parameter cloud match `Function<String,Boolean>`. So the compiler treats `Demo::b` as `Function<String,Boolean>` and cast it.